# Rename Derby Schema

Tags: java, sql, derby

I have severales Derby database already created and with data.

I need to change the schema name of each one so i am looking for an efficient way of renaming the schema or exporting all the data and importing it in a freshley created database.

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

```
create table mynewschema.mynewtable( column-definitions... );

insert into table mynewschema.mynewtable select * from myoldschema.myoldtable;

drop table myoldschema.myoldtable;
```

Comment: I have tables with identity columns. ¿How can i preserve that data?

Comment: It's a little bit trickier with identity columns. You can either (a) insert the data as is, then alter the identity column to restart at the next available number, or (b) name all the columns EXCEPT the identity columns in your INSERT ... SELECT statement, and have the identity columns regenerate their values. Technique (b), of course, doesn't preserve the values, though.